# How do I retrieve and use data I get with Http GET Requests in c#

Tags: c#, http

So I am trying to use GET requests with c# but nothing is really working out.
I wanted to use the site https://covid19.mathdro.id/api as a test to see if I can get the info out of there and use it in a windows form. But I can't seem to figure out how. The only guides I found weren't really that helpful and it just confused me more. Would anyone be able to help me out?

I have tried to use the HttpClient with JSON.net but I get confused in it.
Been trying for the past 2 hours since I never dealt with HTTP GET Requests in c# other than with Python.

Comment: Use [`HttpClient.GetStringAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.getstringasync?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: Use `HttpClient` to grab data, use `JSON.Net` in order to manipulate the JSON. I'd recommend creating objects to represent the data - it just makes things so much easier, though it does depend on if the response is structured and consistent. Working with objects by deserialising the response will remove 99% of the code you would write by hand.

Comment: I have gone over these before but I am not too sure what I have to do with them. I've tried but none of it really worked. @Charleh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the 'Newtonsoft.Json' nuget package.

```
async Task<JToken> GetREST(string uri)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(uri);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        // HTTP GET
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("");
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var jsonData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return JToken.Parse(jsonData);
        }
    }
    return null;
}

async private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var jObj = await GetREST("https://covid19.mathdro.id/api");
    var confirmed = jObj["confirmed"];
    Console.WriteLine("Confirmed:" + confirmed["value"]);
    var confirmedJSON = await GetREST(confirmed["detail"].ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(confirmedJSON);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was able to convert this into a function I can easily call and access the data with a click of a button.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the accepted answer, you can always work with the data as objects by deserializing - I prefer this method over using `JToken` etc as it tends to be very easy to work with the objects (there's often less boilerplate to pull bits of data from the response).

```cs
        public async Task<CovidData> GetCovidData(string uri)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(uri);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("");
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var jsonData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CovidData>(jsonData);
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

The objects you'd deserialize to would look like this:

```cs
    public class CovidData
    {
        public ValueDetailPair Confirmed { get; set; }

        public ValueDetailPair Recovered { get; set; }

        public ValueDetailPair Deaths { get; set; }
    }

    public class ValueDetailPair
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }

        // If you need the link to the detail it would be deserialized to this string member
        public string Detail { get; set; }
    }
```

It really does depend on preference and your use case though.

example:

```
var data = await GetCovidData("https://covid19.mathdro.id/api");

Console.WriteLine(data.Confirmed.Value);
Console.WriteLine(data.Confirmed.Detail);
Console.WriteLine(data.Recovered.Value);
```